# How to toggle warning squiggles vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

The linter that I'm using in vscode is not very accurate so I want to hide the squiggles occasionally.  Is there any way to do that?  Ideally, I want to bind this function to a shortcut key as well.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: It's Julia.  Apparently the vscode extension had a bug.  It seems to have gotten better now and I'll try again.  Thanks for the answer below.

Comment: What linter are you using? Linters usually support granular control with arguments (that need to be provided in the command line) and directives (those can be supplied as comments in the code) that disable particular messages.